# Can Spark store last 10 minutes data for real time application

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, logstash, apache-kafka

I am trying to make a real time analytics application. The overall procedure that I need to follow is: Logstash pumping .log data file to kafka producer topic, kafka producer send to kafka consumer topic. Then, after that I need Spark should read the kafka consumer topic to take input of last minutes data from kafka consumer topic to get real time analytics and simultaneously kafka consumer should write the data to hdfs for later historical analysis. I have read that Spark can read from hdfs but can spark read directly from kafka consumer topic? The procedure that I am following is right or not? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First of all, your idea could be possible. However, you might have to consider performance of Spark-stream, as well. Since Spark-stream works in micro-batch environment, no in real-time system, spark stream can be slow sometimes.  If you want to get better performance, it would be better for you to use flink.

see also :
[flink-streaming](http://www.slideshare.net/GyulaFra/flink-streaming-43445818)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for your response. Going through it now

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can read directly from Spark. Just read the Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Thanks for your reference link. Pretty much helpful